# why compiler gives undefined reference

Tags: c++

I have this code:

in header file

```
     class SocialNet {
         private:
               // some data 
         public:
               // some other operations

          template <typename T, typename V> 
            T find(V identifier, const vector<T>& objects) const;   
      };
```

in .cpp file

```
  // in that file, I haven't use that function
  // I have four other template functions used in that header, and compiler have 
  //not   give any error 
    template <typename T, typename V> 
    T find(V identifier, const vector<T>& objects) const {

         // some things to do required job
     }
```

in main.cpp

```
// I have used that function, for the first time in that file
```

When I compile, I have below error;

```
/main.cpp .. undefined reference to SocialNet :: find ( ....  ) ...
```

**Why?**

With explanation, please, inform me about what the undefined reference means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not implement a template in a `.cpp` file, the function definition of `find` should be there in the header file. See this FAQ [Why can't I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12) for more details.

Comment: Are there any way of implemeting template in .cpp ?

Comment: @fatai: You can separate them, but it breaks encapsulation in any case. Using include guards (of course), I would NOT include the ".h" file in the ".cpp" file in this case; rather, at the end (before the include guard) of the .h file, `#include "yourfile.cpp"`

Comment: @fatai: You can if your compiler supports `export` keyword which is very unlikely. Otherwise no as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to write `SocialNet::` when defining `find`

```
template <typename T, typename V> 
T SocialNet::find(V identifier, const vector<T>& objects) const {
//^^^^^^^^^^^ note this!

 }
```

`SocialNet::` tells the compiler that the function `find` is a member function of class SocialNet. In the absence of `SocialNet::`, the compiler will treat find as free function!

Comment: Can you give me explanation why I should do that, please ?

Comment: Because if you don't do that, compiler will consider it to be a global function.

Comment: @fatai:... `SocialNet::` tells the compiler that the function `find` is a member function of class `SocialNet`. In the absence of `SocialNet::`, the compiler will treat `find` as free function!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the class name before `T find(...)` definition.

```
template <typename T, typename V> 
T SocialNet :: find(V identifier, const vector<T>& objects) const {

     // some things to do required job
}
```

You need to place `SocialNet` before `find(...)` because `find(...)` is declared in scope of class `SocialNet`. Since defining the functionality outside the scope of the class declaration, it needs to be explicitly mentioned that the method being defined belongs to class `SoicalNet`. Note that `::` is the scope resolution operator. Also, you need to include the header in the source file `SocialNet.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

You did not scope your function. That is, you did not preface it with your class name and scope operator (in this case `SocialNet::`).

When implementing functions outside of the class itself, you must scope the function in order to make it work properly so the compiler knows which function it is compiling (i.e. two classes can have two different functions with the same name).

The `undefined reference` error comes particularly from the compiler when you have declared a function in a class, but have not implemented it (you need `{}` braces to implement a void function which does nothing; a semi-colon after the signature is purely a declaration)

Regards,
Dennis M.